# Local_PR_Branch and orgin/PR_Branch have diverged after different rebase in 2 devices

Tags: git, github

So in my work laptop A, I checkout from main and had a feature branch, and submit for PR request, say PR branch.

Then I refreshed my whole environment, so all local files are lost.

Then I checked out the PR branch, and rebase to the latest main.

Now I want to push it into the remote PR branch, but "git status" returns "Your branch and origin/PR_branch" have diverged
and have 4000 and 4 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

What should I do to accomplish this? Should I just do "git push --force"?

Comment: yes, you should just `push --force`.